# Converting bounding box with relative coordinates into absolute ones

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, extents

I have run the yolov5 model to predict trees in imagery with a geocoordinate. I got the bounding box objects with relative coordinates after running the model. I would like to have these bounding boxes with the absolute coordinate system as the imagery (NZTM 2000).

How do I do this?

Below are my bounding box information and original imagery for the prediction.

[image]

The information of bounding box is above.

The imagery with the bounding box is
[image]

The extent of the imagery in the NZTM coordinates as follow:
the coordinate system of imagery: NZGD 2000 New Zealand Transverse Mercator.

```
The extent of imagery: top: 5,702,588.730967 m, bottom: 5,702,581.666007 m, left:1,902,830.371719m, right: 1,902,837.436679m
```